# Procedure in DB2 - SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE

Tags: db2, procedure

Hi I am trying to write a DB2 procedure, which would have been a simple task in SQL Server but seems terribly difficult in DB2

Script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TT.PURGE_LOGS ()
  LANGUAGE SQL  
  SPECIFIC atomic_proc   
  ap:  BEGIN ATOMIC            
     DELETE FROM TT.DTL
     WHERE LOGID IN 
     (SELECT LOGID FROM TT.HDR
     WHERE LOGTYPE <> 120 AND CRDATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAY FROM sysibm.sysdummy1); 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000';        
     DELETE LOGID FROM TT.HDR
     WHERE LOGTYPE <> 120 AND CRDATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAY FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

END ap

Error:
SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: `SELECT LOGID FROM TT.HDR
     WHERE LOGTYPE <> 120 AND CRDATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAY FROM sysibm.sysdummy1` doesn't look like a valid subselect; for one, it seems to have two `FROM` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested by mustaccio in comment, your syntax is not valid.

If the datatype of CRDATE is DATE then did you mean:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE TT.PURGE_LOGS ()
  LANGUAGE SQL  
  SPECIFIC atomic_proc   
  ap:  
  BEGIN ATOMIC            
     DELETE FROM TT.DTL
     WHERE LOGID IN 
                    (SELECT LOGID 
                     FROM TT.HDR
                     WHERE LOGTYPE <> 120 
                     AND CRDATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
                    ) ;
     DELETE FROM TT.HDR
     WHERE LOGTYPE <> 120 
     AND CRDATE < CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS
     ;

END ap
```

Note that your `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` should probably be in an exception handler, otherwise its purpose is unclear as you wrote it.